# When is the model attached to the controller?

Tags: ember.js

At what point is the model attached to the controller? And, is there a hook when the model is there?

Because I face the following problem of not being able to access the model to do some computations with the data in it:

```
App.ResultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        // LOCAL, blocking call!
        return {messages : this.store.all('message').toArray()};
    }
});

App.ResultsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init : function(){
        this._super();
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.get('model'));
        console.log(this.get('model.messages'));
        this._someComputation();
    },

    _someComputation : function(){
        this.get('model.messages').forEach(function(message){
            //do something
        }
    }
});
```

This prints:

```
Class { [...] model: messages: Array[58]0: Class1: Class2: [...] Class57: Class length: 58}
null 
null
```

So, basically I can see the model in the console but when accessing it programmatically in the `init` function it's not there (yet?).
Or is this is the wrong way (or place) to do some computations with the model data?

**edit:**
The controller of a child route can access the model, so this would work as a workaround:

```
App.ResultsIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "results",
    parentController : Ember.computed.alias('controllers.results'),

    init : function(){
        console.log("ResultsIndexController created");
        console.log(this.get('parentController').get('model'));
    }
});
```

Prints:

```
ResultsIndexController created
{messages: Array[55]}
```

But I'd rather have it in the parent controller such that all children can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's attached during `setupController` which happens in the route, after init, when the model has been resolved.  The code essentially looks like this:

```
App.ResultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        // LOCAL, blocking call!
        return {messages : this.store.all('message').toArray()};
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model){
      controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

If you wanted you could do it during `setupController`, it's a fairly common practice to override it to add additional functionality.

```
App.ResultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        // LOCAL, blocking call!
        return {messages : this.store.all('message').toArray()};
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model){
      this._super(controller, model);
      controller._someComputation();
    }
});
```

Additionally your model hook says it's a blocking call, but you aren't returning a promise, so that isn't true (but maybe that's just a copy paste foo)

Comment: The documentation states that `store.all()` directly returns a `RecordArray` whereas `store.find()` returns a promise, so I assumed this is blocking but I must have been wrong there.

Comment: If you returned store.find() to the model hook it would work, but not if you returned { foo: store.find() }.  Then it wouldn't know there was a promise hidden in the object.